# Is it possible to implement a standalone notification feed in getStream.io?

Tags: getstream-io

I am building a social media website. My timeline feature is built and works fine. I want to implement a notification system for users same as in prominent social media (X likes your post, Y commented on your photos, Z started following you etc).
However it seems in Stream you need to have timeline and user feed also for notification feed. Is it possible to have just the notification feed?
If not, is it possible to change the feed type to "timeline" and use a timeline feed for notifications?

Answer (score 0):

There are broadly two types of activity feed: Flat and Aggregated.  The Flat feeds are used for timelines and can be followed.

Aggregated Feeds can't be followed and are used for things like:

'Eric followed 10 people'
'Julie and 14 others liked your photo'

The Notification Feed inherits from the Aggregation Feed with the addition of a seen/read status - perfect for notifications in social apps/websites.

The timeline and notification feeds are separate and not reliant on each other and can be used independently of each other.

The aggregate/notification feeds are for individual users to consume and not seen by other users.  Their format is `notification:{userId}`.  Therefore, the id of the user should be same as the id in your application, and you would need to have that user exist in both systems and kept in sync.

Hope this helps.  More information can be seen here: https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/react-native/flat_feeds/?language=javascript